# Spark read data from Cassandra error org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String is not a valid external type for schema of string

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, data-extraction

I have a Cassandra table that is created as the following(in cqlsh)

```
CREATE TABLE blog.session( id int PRIMARY KEY, visited text);
```

I write data to Cassandra and it looks like this

```
id  | visited
1   |  Url1-Url2-Url3
```

I then try to read it using spark Cassandra connector(2.5.1).

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("ReadFromCass")
    .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
    .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
    .getOrCreate()

  import sparkSession.implicits._
  val readSessions = sparkSession.sqlContext
    .read
    .cassandraFormat("table1", "keyspace1").load().show()
```

However, it seems to be unable to read the visited since it is a text object with dashes in between words. The error occurs as

```
org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String is not a valid external type for schema of string
```

any ideas on why spark is unable to read this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seemed to be the version of the spark-cassandra-connector. Instead of using "2.5.1" use "3.0.0-beta"

Comment: yes, it's known problem with Spark 3.0 & SCC 3.0.0-alpha... Anyway, for Spark 3.0 SCC 3.0 should be used, and 2.5.1 should be used for Spark 2.4

Comment: also checked the fix. after changing to "3.0.0-beta" I was able to retrieve textual information from Cassandra data source via spark read, 10x mate